# Spring:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI warning

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Trying to run a spring hibernate project.Please, help to find my mistakes. I have got error "WARN :No mapping found  .
This is my Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SpringMVCHibernate</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SpringMVCHibernate</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

This is the SpringMVCHibernate-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring"/>

        <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="Root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){

        if(p.getId() == 0){
            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);
        }else{
            //existing person, call update
            this.personService.updatePerson(p);
        }

        return "redirect:/persons";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id){

        this.personService.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

}
```

Folder structure:
[image]

I am getting this error:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVCHibernate'
```

Comment: Is there any request mapping for / ?  
please  post code of the controller.

Comment: try changing your url pattern to /** in web.xml, also, controller code should be here

Comment: Controller class added...please assist